# How can I set a gradient background on a WebView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to apply a gradient bg color to a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)... 
I'm use many sample code but not display gradient color...
if anyone know the ans post me..

Comment: what are you doing that isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A WebView has a [default background color of white](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29), drawn in front of any drawables. You'll need to use the following code to make it transparent:

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);        
        webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Then apply a gradient background as follows:

Create a file called gradient-bg.xml in your /res/drawable-mdpi folder.

Add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient 
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:endColor="#000000"
            android:angle="90"
            />
</shape>
```

Then in your layout files you can add the drawable to any view or layout via the background property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient-bg"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Oh...try web.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient); It may not work but I'll update your question anyway.

Comment: Hi I'm use setBackgroundResource this is change TextView bg as gradient color but not change webview bg as gradient

Comment: See my updated answer - you must make the backgroundColor transparent!

Comment: web.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(135, 205,44)); use this code change bg color but I'm use this web.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient); cannot change bg color as gradient

Comment: Set the color to 0 as in my code above and call setBackgroundResource as well

Comment: I'm use this code only change Linear layout,TextView,button...etc but cannot change WebVIew bg color

Comment: Forget the linear layout - you can do it all in code in onCreate or otherwise: WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);        
        webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient);

Comment: Wow you r really great... WebView bg as change gradient color... Thanks you vary much.....

Comment: I have the same problem.  On Emulator is works but when installed on device it does not display gradient.  Why?

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) // Android v3.0+
       try {
        Method method = View.class.getMethod("setLayerType", int.class, Paint.class);
        method.invoke(whelpDescriptionText, 1, new Paint()); // 1 = LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE (API11)
       } catch (Exception e) {
      } //added this then worked

Answer (score 3):

put this in the drawable folder as a XML file, and then use it as a background for some Widget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#AAAAAA"
            android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Hi Reflog, I am add this code in drawable...... and add one line java code web.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.gradient); but not changed bg color

Comment: Don't set it as a color, set it as a background drawable

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. Just add this XML file in ur drawable as gradient_box.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
    android:startColor="#B8E7F3"
    android:endColor="#01CBFB"
    android:angle="45"/>
 <padding android:left="3dp"
    android:top="3dp"
    android:right="3dp"
    android:bottom="3dp" />
 <corners android:radius="6dp" />

  </shape>
```

Comment: Hi Hussain, I am add this code in drawable...... and add one line java code web.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.gradient); but not changed bg color

Comment: @Jeeva: Im using this code.. Its working for me.. try to add it in XML and see `android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"`

Comment: Hi hussain,This code I'm use but TextView bg as gradient color but not change webview bg as gradient

Answer (score 0):

To make webview transperent use
webview.setBackgroundColor(0)